# Importing a dataset into a matrix

Tags: r, csv, dataset

Dear StackOverflow community,

I have a dataset from my university projects I am trying to parse and run some calculations on. It looks similar to:

```
Month,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7
x.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
x.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
x.3,0,0,0,6,5,5,,,15
x.4,0,0,0,7,7,,,,15
x.5,1,1,1,11,7,5,,,0
x.6,1,1,1,14,6,,,,0
x.7,1,1,1,17,5,,,,15
x.8,1,1,1,21,4,,,,15
x.9,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0
x.10,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0
x.11,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0
x.12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
x.13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
x.14,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
x.20,orchid,,,orchid,rose,orchid,orchid,orchid,
x.23,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1
x.24,,,,,buttercup,buttercup,buttercup,buttercup,lilac
x.25,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1
x.26,,,,17,,,,,15
x.27,,,,999,,,,,15
```

I try to then import it like so:

```r
data <- read.csv("~/data_munging/data.csv", header=F)
my_matrix <- as.matrix(data)
```

The issue here is that the dataset's first column is actually the names of the variables, and `as.matrix()` does not read it as row (variable) names.

(There are also holes in some of the data, but that I will leave for another question).

I am new to R and am wondering What am I Doing Wrong™?

**Update:**
As per Justin's comments, here is how import the dataset and the `str()` it produces:

```
> sample_data <- read.csv("~/data_munging/sample_data.csv", header=F)
> str(sample_data)
'data.frame':   28 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ V1 : Factor w/ 28 levels "Month","x.1","x.10",..: 1 2 13 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 ...
 $ V2 : Factor w/ 4 levels "","0","1","orchid": 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 ...
 $ V3 : int  2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ V4 : int  3 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ V5 : Factor w/ 12 levels "","0","1","11",..: 8 2 2 9 10 4 5 6 7 3 ...
 $ V6 : Factor w/ 9 levels "","0","1","4",..: 4 2 2 5 7 7 6 5 4 3 ...
 $ V7 : Factor w/ 7 levels "","0","1","4",..: 4 2 2 5 1 5 1 1 1 3 ...
 $ V8 : Factor w/ 6 levels "","0","1","5",..: 4 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 ...
 $ V9 : Factor w/ 6 levels "","0","1","6",..: 4 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 ...
 $ V10: Factor w/ 6 levels "","0","1","15",..: 5 2 2 4 4 2 2 4 4 2 ...
```

The reason I believe it should be a matrix is because this way it reads the `Month` as a factor and its levels are the row names instead of moths (month of year).

**Update 2:** Now with the original dataset in CSV.

Comment: Its hard to tell what your data actually look like from this, can you use `str(data)` and `dput(head(data))` to show us the structure.  Why do you think it should be in a matrix?  You have character and numeric data and a matrix can only be one data type.  It sounds like a `data.frame` (the way it is already) is more fitting to your data.

Comment: It's not really a proper data frame already- its *transpose* is a data frame (since each row is of a shared type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a transpose method for matrices and dataframes which returns a matrix.:

```
tdat <- t( read.table(text="Month,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7
 x.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
 x.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
 x.3,0,0,0,6,5,5,,,15
 x.4,0,0,0,7,7,,,,15
 x.5,1,1,1,11,7,5,,,0
 x.6,1,1,1,14,6,,,,0
 x.7,1,1,1,17,5,,,,15
 x.8,1,1,1,21,4,,,,15
 x.9,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0
 x.10,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0
 x.11,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0
 x.12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
 x.13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
 x.14,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
 x.20,orchid,,,orchid,rose,orchid,orchid,orchid,
 x.23,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1
 x.24,,,,,buttercup,buttercup,buttercup,buttercup,lilac
 x.25,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1
 x.26,,,,17,,,,,15
 x.27,,,,999,,,,,15", sep=",", header=FALSE, as.is=TRUE) )
 # It might not be immediately obvious that the transpose function converts to matrix
 newdat <- tdat[-1, ]
 colnames(newdat) <- dat[1,]
 newdat <- as.data.frame(newdat)   
# when converted back , everything is factors. Will need to convert to get numeric
  newdat[ , -grep("20|24", names(newdat) ) ] <- 
                    lapply(newdat[ , -grep("20|24", names(newdat) )], 
                             function(x) as.numeric( as.character(x) ))
# Need to use grep to convert character-names to numeric so can use negative indexing
# and used the redundant `as.numeric(as.character(x))` to illustrate good practice.
```

Resulting in:

```
> newdat
    Month x.1 x.2 x.3 x.4 x.5 x.6 x.7 x.8 x.9 x.10 x.11 x.12 x.13 x.14   x.20 x.23      x.24 x.25 x.26 x.27
V2      3   2   2   3   3   4   4   3   3   2    2    3    2    2    3 orchid    2              2    1    1
V3      1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   1    1    1    1    1    2   <NA>    1      <NA>    1   NA   NA
V4      2   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   1    1    1    1    1    1   <NA>    1      <NA>    1   NA   NA
V5      4   2   2   6   5   5   5   5   5   3    3    3    2    2    3 orchid    3              3    3    3
V6      5   2   2   5   5   7   6   6   6   3    3    3    2    2    3   rose    3 buttercup    3    1    1
V7      5   2   2   5   1   6   1   1   1   3    3    3    2    2    3 orchid    3 buttercup    2    1    1
V8      6   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   3    3    3    2    2    3 orchid    3 buttercup    3    1    1
V9      7   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   3    3    3    2    2    3 orchid    3 buttercup    3    1    1
V10     8   2   2   4   4   3   3   4   4   2    2    2    3    2    3           3     lilac    3    2    2
```

I do notice that there are both a 999 value that is probably a missing value indicator, as well as two different values for missing in the factor columns. That is a side-effect of how read.table input the columns. It "thought" that the V3 and V4 columns were numeric and handled sequential commas as a true missing, whereas all the other columns (before transposition) were seen as factor or character variables and sequential commas got turned into "" which is not the same as _NA_character or the NA for factors.

Comment: Thanks for the input @DWin! I pasted the original CSV dataset I used in there, to better illustrate the issue.